# pass margin-left property in div

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsx

I am trying to add a css property in div. How can i pass `margin-left: 2px` in following div?

```
    (<div style={{width: `${widthValue}%`}} key = {i}>
      <progress
        {...customProps}
        style={{ color: group.color }}
        className={classes}
        max={100}
        value={100}
        aria-valuemax={100}
        aria-valuemin={0}
        aria-valuenow={widthValue}
        tabIndex="-1"
    />
  </div>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inline styles and camelCase.

`style={{ marginLeft: 2 }}`

**Note**: Default unit is `px`.